# get the figure using nested for loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, stacked

Any ideas how to write Java program in a class named Window that produces the preceding figure as output. I have to use nested for loops to print the repeated parts of the figure. 
I've tried lots of times, no success :(

Write a Java program in a class named Window that produces the preceding figure as output. Use nested for loops to print the repeated parts of the figure. Once you get it to work, add one class constant to your program so that the size of the figure can be changed simply by changing that constant's value. The example output shown is at a constant size of 3, but if you change the constant, the figure should grow larger and wider proportionally.

```
+===+===+
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
+===+===+
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
+===+===+
```

OK i've got this, but still need to get rid of 3 bottom lines - any idea?

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (int plus = 1; plus <= 2; plus++) {
            System.out.print("+");
        for (int shave = 1; shave <= 3; shave++) {
                System.out.print("=");
            }
            }
        System.out.print("+");
            System.out.println();
    for (int time = 1; time <= 3; time++) {
         for (int kav = 1; kav <= 3; kav++) {
                 System.out.print("|");
             for (int rev = 1; rev <= 3; rev++) {
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
             }
         System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Is this is homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, I've got several ideas.  What ideas do you have?

Comment: for (int line = 1; line <= 9; line ++) {
        for (int plus = 1; plus <= 3; plus++) {
            System.out.print("+");
        for (int eq = 1; eq <= 6; eq++) {
            System.out.print("=");
        for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        }
   }

Comment: Edit the code into your post, and point out what, exactly, the problem is.

Comment: This is a stupid homework assignment. When would this ever be useful?

Comment: @Jivings it is perfectly valid to ask about homework here as long as it conforms to the guidelines.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That wasn't what I was saying. I was implying that it's a stupid homework assignment to give out.

Comment: I think that teacher you have should definetely try to find better examples/exercises for teaching nested loops. This one is just too weird/useless...

Comment: Well, it's not a teacher's assignment, I'm using this source http://webster.cs.washington.edu:8080/practiceit/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+2nd+edition%2FChapter+2&problem=2-e19-Window to practice more in Java

Comment: @Jivings, if it is hard, then perhaps it is not _so_ stupid?

Comment: Easy ;-)  `for(int i=0;i<1;) for(;i++<1;) System.out.print("+===+===+\n|   |   |\n|   |   |\n|   |   |\n+===+===+\n|   |   |\n|   |   |\n|   |   |\n+===+===+");`

Comment: it should be at least 4 for statements

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I see no practical use for this kind of exercise.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are Looking for:

```
        final int BLOCK_SIZE = 2;
        for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
            System.out.print("+===+");
            for(int j=0; j<1; j++){
                System.out.println("===+");
                for(int k=0; k<BLOCK_SIZE; k++){
                    System.out.println("|   |   |\n|   |   |\n|   |   |");
                    for(int l=0; l<1; l++){
                        System.out.println("+===+===+");
                    }
                } System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Took sometime to achieve your expected result, see if it works for you?

```
public class Homework
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            for (int line = 1; line <= 3; line ++)
            {

                NEWLINE:

                    for (int plus = 1; plus <= 3; plus++)
                    {
                        System.out.print("+");
                        if (plus == 3) 
                        {
                            for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
                            {
                                if (line == 3)
                                {
                                    break NEWLINE;
                                }
                                System.out.println("");
                                System.out.print(" |         |          |");
                                if (k == 3)
                                {
                                    System.out.println();
                                    break NEWLINE;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        for (int eq = 1; eq <= 6; eq++)
                        {
                            if (eq % 4 == 0)
                            {                           
                                break;
                            }
                            System.out.print("=");
                        }

                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice use of the break statement there

Comment: Thank you Jasonw, but I need to use only nested for loops

Comment: In general it works, but how can I change constant height if I have this line: System.out.println("+===+===+");?

Comment: @alya that could probably be your homework as many posted their suggested here that give you many idea how to achieve your expected result in many ways. But probably Johnydep answer come the closest to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I was going through random questions and I found no one actually answered correctly by correcting the code you posted. So here I post my code with nested for loops and it satisfies all your criteria, giving the correct output.

```
int BLOCK_SIZE = 4;
for (int i=1; i<BLOCK_SIZE; i++){
    for(int j=1; j<BLOCK_SIZE; j++){
        System.out.print("+===");
    }
    System.out.println("+");
    for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
        for(int j=1; j<BLOCK_SIZE; j++){
            System.out.print("|   ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
}
for(int j=1; j<BLOCK_SIZE; j++){
        System.out.print("+===");
    }
System.out.println("+");
```

Another approach using some if statements

- Here I make use of the fact that every (4n+1) line has '+' replacing '|' and '=' replacing 'whitespace'

  ```
  int BLOCK_SIZE = 5;
  int length = BLOCK_SIZE*4-4;
  char one,two;

  for(int i=0; i<=length; i++){
      if(i%4!=0){one='|';two=' ';}
      else{one='+';two='=';}
      for(int j=0; j<=length; j++){
          if(j%4==0) {
          System.out.print(one);
          }
          else {
          System.out.print(two);
          }
      }
      System.out.println(); 
  }
  ```

Granted it's a homework problem, but we can have fun cracking them even if they serve no real life purpose. Such is the happiness that can be gotten from coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 4;
    String output1 = "";
    String output2 = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        output1 += "|   ";
    }
    output1 += "|";
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        output2 += "+===";
    }
    output2 += "+";
    for(int i = 0; i < rows*4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println((i % 4 != 0)?output1:output2);
    }
    System.out.println(output2);
```

Comment: I wrote it "I have to use nested for loops to print the repeated parts of the figure"

Comment: You're going to need to use a conditional statement for this to distinguish between which type of row to display. I updated the code. Its better and uses only 1 `if` statement.

Comment: Really stupid homework: you can replace any if by a for (example, `if(i % 4 !=0)` is the same as `for(int cnt = 0; cnt < 1 && i % 4 != 0; cnt++)`... so just replace the ifs with this pattern ;)

Comment: thanks, it looks good, but I need to use 4 for loops, it should be really easy, but I can't figure out it yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Could be refactored to be more pretty, but will work:

`static String[][] array = { { "x", "="}, { "|", " "}};`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            System.out.print(getSign(y, x));
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

private static String getSign(int y, int x) {   
    int modY = y % 4;
    int modX = x % 4;
    return array[getPos(modY)][getPos(modX)];
}

private static int getPos(int mod) {
    return (mod & 1) | ((mod & 2) >> 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest way.

```
public class Window {
    public static final int size = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x=0; x<2; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y<2; y++){
                System.out.print("+");
                for (int z=0;z<size; z++) {
                    System.out.print("=");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("+");
            for (int i = 0; i<size; i ++) {
                for (int j = 0; j<2; j++) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                    for (int k = 0; k<size; k++) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("|");
            }
        }
         for (int y = 0; y<2; y++){
                System.out.print("+");
                for (int z=0;z<size; z++) {
                    System.out.print("=");
                }
            }
        System.out.println("+");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Window{
    public static final int size=3;
    public static void main(String[] args){
       for (int p = 1; p <= 2; p++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <=2; i++) {
                System.out.print("+");
                for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
                    System.out.print("=");
                }
            }
                System.out.print("+");
                System.out.println();
            for (int k = 1; k <= size; k++) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                    for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.print("+");
            for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
                System.out.print("=");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("+");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's this? Probably, you should explain why did you answer 3 y.o. question. Why do you think your answer is better than already posted answers?